# Binding к данным другого DataSourse взависимости от текущего

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

Ломаю голову как сделать, может дадите правильное направление.
Есть `DataTable table1` с данными, у нее есть колонка `TypeID` типа `Int32` которая указывает на тип из таблицы `typesTable`. Также есть таблица `DataTable typesTable` с колонками `id` типа `Int32` и `BitmapSource` типа `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource`, `BitmapSource` иногда меняется.

Теперь со стороны XAML есть `DataTemplate` контрола элементы которого `DataView(table1)`, вопрос вот в чем: "Как в этот дататемплейт засунуть картинку, которая будет меняться в зависимости от `table1[TypeID]` и `typesTable[BitmapSource]`"

XAML:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="StructuralSubdivisionItemDataTemplate">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="{Binding Path=TypeID, Converter=???, ConverterParameter=???}" /> 
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DisplayString}"/>
  </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Надеюсь всё правильно объяснил, если что пишите замечания, подправлю вопрос...

Comment: Можете код XAML добавить?

Comment: Добавил XAML, но боюсь он ничего Вам не скажет нового.

Comment: Почему нельзя создать модель представления, которая вытаскивает нужные данные из таблиц и выставляет нужные свойства?

Comment: есть тут одна проблема, BitmapSource изначально может быть null, а потом появиться и наоборот. Хотелось, чтобы за этим следил Binding.

Comment: @Vlad добавил пустой `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap` и меняю его по мере необходимости, или очищаю. Всё заработало, спасибо за наводку. Можете сделать как ответ, я отмечу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам не нужно выставлять наружу `DataTable`. Нужно создать модель представления, которая будет оборачивать `DataTable` и выставлять наружу только нужные свойства.

При обновлении DataRow нужно будет каким-то образом обновлять и эту модель представления.